# User Permissions in serene for visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have created a project as mentioned in - https://volkanceylan.gitbooks.io/serenity-guide/content/tutorials/movies/creating_movie_table.html
I have also ceated the MovieDB as mentioned in the guidelines. I am trying to give a role access to this Movie table but Movie doesnt get listed in the UserPermissions tab.

Has anyone ever faced such problem or has anyone worked with serenity at all ?

Comment: Did you perform the next step (Generating Code For Movie Table)?  This is what actually generates the Class in serenity, and it has a section about the Permission Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serenity permissions are not based on tables. What you put on rows with ReadPermission etc attributes are used. In guide, we didn't touch that detail, so rows has Administration permission. If you change permission for Movie rows to something else e.g. "MovieDB", it will be shown in permissions dialog.

Comment: you're welcome, consider accepting answer if it's helped ;)